# Is there a tutorial video to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

Many times I've written [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the comment section of questions from newcomers. Still, the same users won't post a MCVE in their following questions, even if they've read it.

Many people are not reading English well and a big portion learns better by watching examples and listening rather than reading. I believe a short video explaining and demonstrating with a few examples on how to produce a MCVE could be beneficial for some people.

Does such a video already exist or is this just an inherently bad idea?

---

**Clarifications:**

1. I meant that a video would be beneficial for those who **want to learn** about creating a MCVE, and understands better (or learns faster) when hearing and listening rather than reading. It will not be of any value for those who don't want to learn.
2. It is merely a change in format from the current help page and not a recursive MCVE in a MCVE.
3. The term MCVE is almost exclusive to the Stack Exchange communities and newcomers must most likely have to learn about it. That's why the help center page exists. The discussion I wanted to have was if a video format of that information would be beneficial.
4. I am not saying that such a video was meant for people who can not read English. Language barriers **diminishes the learning process** which makes it harder to **fully** understand new concepts. By providing a video we might help more people to understand, or people to understand better, what a MCVE is (or not, that's the discussion to be had), because clearly there are many people who don't understand or needs more clarification.

Comment: Bad idea, imo. That will just be another futile effort towards educating users that simply do not want to learn. I've encountered quite a few users that asked me for explanation after linking to the MCVE section, but some just choose to ignore it. A video won't change anything I believe.

Comment: @Seth I meant those who are willing to learn. I know that unwilling people will never learn. What I meant was for those who are bad at English or learns better by seeing and listening. As you said, you've been asked for a further explanation after linking the MCVE section, which means some people might have trouble understanding when the only information of the subject lies in text.

Comment: 'I meant those who are willing to learn', well, on OS, that seems to be a set with few members:(   Anyway, when you've made the video, maybe we could view it to suggest improvements or vote for addition to the tour/help?  Which languages will the audio and/or subtitles be in?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I get where you're coming from, but based on my personal experience I'd say that those willing to learn will not hesitate to reply to my comment, asking for clarification, which I'm happily going to give. I just don't see how a video would add a significant amount of value.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I don't quite understand your comment. Of course such a video should be English in both audio and subtitles (unless several videos of different languages exists). An I asked this question to hear if there were any videos already available (and if it would be a bad idea to link to it/them), so I don't know why you're commenting on me creating one and submitting it for improvements and suggestions.

Comment: @Seth Okay, I see your point and will continue to reflect some more on this

Comment: @EricAya Your learning ability is definitely diminished by language barriers. If you look at a tutorial where someone speaks English in a broken accent versus someone speaking in "clean" English, you'll learn faster from the second one. Also, a MCVE is mysterious to a newcomer, since that term is almost exclusive to SO. Learning it is a new concept for many. Sure, an experienced developer might learn what it is quicker but it still requires learning, and since many newcomers are must likely new to development, they'll need help in their process of understanding MCVE.

Comment: @EricAya What I meant was that creating a MCVE is something you have to learn, which is affected by language barriers. That's why we have the help center, so newcomers can learn to create a MCVE. Knowing how to create a MCVE is not directly correlated with being a developer. When you're developing an application there's nothing directly teaching you not to post pseudo-code or your whole app on a Q&A-site. Also, many people posting questions aren't experienced developers and can't think as a developer, which is why they need to be taught.

Comment: @Ðаn That's a valid point, I think I have to reflect about it

Comment: 'a MCVE is mysterious to a newcomer' .... why?  "Hello Mr. Garage technician, my car doesn't run right". "What's wrong with it?".  "I just told you - It doesn't run right!".  "Umm.. OK, bring it in so that we can look at the problem in our service bay".  "Why do you need the car? Can't you just fix it over the phone?"...."click".... "Helllo?  Hello?...."

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Clearly, a MCVE is more than just stating the error of the code. MCVE is also an exclusive term used just inside Stack Exchange which follows that people that haven't encounter them before doesn't know about MCVE, unless being exposed through other people which use SO who have used the term.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Google.

Comment: The phrasing M.C.V.E. may be mostly used on Stack Overflow but it is not *"an exclusive term used just inside Stack Exchange"*. The concept is commonly used in helping with problem solving. The helper asks them to "explain the problem", to "explain the core of the problem, omitting the unnecessary bits, the bits that work OK", to "focus on the essence of the problem".

Comment: @Ðаn I didn't mean that it was solely because of difficulty with English. I believe that creating a MCVE is something you have to learn, which is much harder if you don't read English fluently. However, my main point was that the help center in a different format than in text might help more people to better understand what a MCVE is. More language specific sites might help those who cannot read English, which definitely could be beneficial.

Comment: @Ðаn That's definitely a greater and more frequent problem, but I'm talking about those who actually want to learn. They have to (and want to) learn how to make a MCVE and all resources out there are in text. Providing this information both visually and aurally might help some (maybe just a few) to process the information faster and better, which could make the information more accessible and easier to understand. I'm not saying it will happen but that's the discussion I wanted to have, and to see if there was a consensus of opinion among other users.

Comment: @AdrianHHH The MCVE section in the help center describes how to ask a question about a problem caused by code. Since the Stack Exchange communities are pretty much dominant in this area it's _"almost exclusive to the Stack Exchange communities"._ I don't think people encounter the concept from many other places than the Stack Exchange communities. At least I hadn't even though I had watched programming tutorials, read books and taken programming courses at university. They don't teach how to ask programing questions on the internet, which is very unfortunate.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I don't think you need to ask permission to create a MCVE video. Just go ahead and do it, make it he best quality you can, and then add a feature request to link to it or embed it in the `[MCVE]` page. If the community likes it, you'll get a lot of support and upvotes, and since the actual change to the leg is trivial, I can't see the team standing in the way of the community's will in this case. Having said that, the hard part is doing the work, and making it quality.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think I have the competence to create a video of high quality since my editing skills and English speaking skills isn't as great as one might want. That's why I asked if one already existed. I was maybe going to give it a try just for fun when I had the time but since there seems to be a huge disapproval I don't really see it being beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

In reality, the only thing "post an MCVE" is saying is, "Get me into the context of your problem so that I can help you with it."  This is a basic tenant of asking questions; one can state a problem that they're having with an application, but until you know *what* problem and *what* application it is, there's not much you can say.

That said, creating a video on how to provide details *for your own question* feels about as useful as the "9" on your microwave.  I won't deny that there's at least a little value to be had to guide users into asking questions, but I say there's a lot *more* value in ensuring those kinds of users don't ask questions 'round here.

I only take this hard-line stance because we're not at everyone's beckon and call; if they want help they have to meet us at least halfway.  Anyone not willing to do that isn't really interested in our help.

Comment: Yes, a MCVE is a fundamental part of asking questions, but we're still seeing people who don't know how to create one. Sure, many of them are unwilling to learn but some just have difficulty fully understand what a MCVE means. Currently, when someone don't know how to create one we link to the MCVE page in the help center for them to learn more. So, why would we be subservient for linking a video rather than text? By providing additional educational tools, aren't we allowing more to be able to meet us halfway?

Comment: Again, it's kind of like the "9" on your microwave.  Sure, it has its place, but how often do you honestly expect to use it?  Same with the videos; they *might* help, but I don't see it helping that often, either.

Comment: Currently, I'm linking to the MCVE page fairly often. I've encountered a few times where it wasn't enough and an explanatory video potentially could have helped. Sure, it might not be necessary for a majority but I do believe many (despite it being necessary) would find it easier to watch a video rather than reading. One group that comes to mind are dyslexics.

Comment: So...I tried to be cynical and slightly humorous, but I suppose I'll be blunt.  If a person who asks a question doesn't care to explain their problem, they're not looking for an actual answer.  This applies both to Stack Overflow and the broader world.  Dyslexia (and dyscalculia by extension) do not preclude a sharp lack of being able to explain one's problem.

Comment: Although, explaining one's problem is not equivalent to a MCVE. Someone could be explaining their problem exceptionally, even if they post their whole application. You could say that it should be common knowledge to not do so, but it really isn't. People need to be taught how to ask a question in a good way. And since it's not really taught anywhere to the standards required by SO, they will have to read themselves to that information at the help center. That information might be easier to receive for many people (especially those with reading disabilities) if provided in video format.